# Confusion on '%' format operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

I have been reading the python documentation on the format operator'%' and have encounter some questions.

---

> A conversion specifier contains two or more characters and has the following components, which must occur in this order:
> 1.The '%' character, which marks the start of the specifier.
>
> 2.Mapping key (optional), consisting of a parenthesised sequence of characters (for example, (somename)).
>
> 3.Conversion flags (optional), which affect the result of some conversion types.
>
> 4.Minimum field width (optional). If specified as an '*' (asterisk), the actual width is read from the next element of the tuple in values, and the object to convert comes after the minimum field width and optional precision.
>
> 5.Precision (optional), given as a '.' (dot) followed by the precision. If specified as '*' (an asterisk), the actual precision is read from the next element of the tuple in values, and the value to convert comes after the precision.
>
> 6.Length modifier (optional).
>
> 7.Conversion type.

---

> A length modifier (h, l, or L) may be present, but is ignored as it is not necessary for Python – so e.g. `%ld` is identical to `%d`.

---

These are the two part that I don't understand

1. For the Minimum field width, what does the `If specified as an '*' (asterisk), the actual width is read from the next element of the tuple in values, and the object to convert comes after the minimum field width and optional precision.`means?
2. Similarly, for the Precision, what does the `If specified as '*' (an asterisk), the actual precision is read from the next element of the tuple in values, and the value to convert comes after the precision.`means?
3. For the Length Modifier`(k,l,L)` what does each of them does to the formatting?

Comment: This is not answering your question, but it's recommended nowadays to use `.format()` and f-strings in favour of `%` syntax. See for example here https://pyformat.info/

Comment: I agree with @tsabsch, both f-strings and `.format()` are [faster than `%`](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#speed). Personally, f-strings are much easier to read, and write, than `.format()`, but `.format()` has more backwards compatibility as f-strings came in with Python 3.6, so won't work in anything earlier.

Comment: Using the `format` method is also more modular. You can define `x = "{} {}"` once, and call `x.format(...)` as often as needed.

Comment: Regarding `*`, it is a placeholder itself. `'%3d' % (9,)` and `'%*d' % (3, 9)` are equivalent.

Comment: This question is too broad; 1 and 2 are essentially one question, but the 3rd one is should be posted separately.